# How to get result of JSON use cURL?

Tags: php, json

i want to get result json from rest api of youtube with this code

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&id=UCkXmLjEr95LVtGuIm3l2dPg&key=AIzaSyB1Xn7nMC1dH04rrMVDcMYICjhM4wWvE0k' );
  curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  $result = json_decode($result, true);
  var_dump($result);

?>
```

but i just get NULL result how to fix it ?

Comment: `var_dump($result);` __before__ decoding.

Comment: "but i just get NULL" — I don't. The code works for me.

Comment: can you use file_get_contents to get content from url. If it not null, please install cURL extension :D

Comment: But i got the result instead of `var_dump($result)`. use `foreach()` and print_r() the value

Comment: Hey... don't put your API keys in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this way to capture the `error`.By the way, your existing code works fine for me, I guess you don't have the php curl installed. **SEE** [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&id=UCkXmLjEr95LVtGuIm3l2dPg&key=AIzaSyB1Xn7nMC1dH04rrMVDcMYICjhM4wWvE0k",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

**EDIT:** If you got the **SSL** issue then set this two lines on **your** existing code

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: i check in my web server xampp php curl have installed and i try that code but i get line error cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: how to fix it??

Comment: @Raafni see mey **EDIT** section of the answer and let me know is that working for you or not?

Comment: @Raafni glad it helps you somehow. By the way you can accept the answer with Green tick. :)